# can i make an unrelated element appear between a parent and child

Tags: html, css

I have an element that contains another element, and due to other parts in the code it would be very hard to disconnect the two elements without breaking things. I have an unrelated element that the child needs to appear above, but the parent is supposed to appear below.

the code below is a recreation of what my attempts and chatgpt questions got me to, the unrelated element still appears above both the parent and the child.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.child {
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.unrelated {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background-color: #00f;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child element
  </div>
</div>

<div class="unrelated">
  Unrelated element
</div>
```

is there any way to make the unrelated element appear between them?

Comment: what do you mean between parent and child? inside parent above child? or on z-index between parent and child?

Comment: the parent should be below the unrelated element, but the child should be above it.

Comment: Could you expand your example code as at the moment parent has nothing in it apart from child so it’s not clear what between would look like. Perhaps also add a sketch of the layout required.

Comment: i don't know why, but for some reason the stackoverflow run code snippet doesn't show properly and i can't figure out how to make it show properly. if you look at what's written in a browser, there's a parent element grey box, inside of which theres a child element red box, on top of which theres an unrelated element blue box. what i need is for the blue box to be under the red box, but still appear over the grey box.

Comment: what it looks like https://imgur.com/yu2Kgts (almost) what im going for https://imgur.com/O3qnAcT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `position: relative` on `.parent` is defining a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) – as long as that is there, `.parent` and `.child` will be stacked together separately of `.unrelated`.

In your toy example, just removing `position: relative` from `.parent` and adding it to `.child` will achieve the required layout. In your final code you'll also need to remove any rules that create a new stacking context between `.child` and its nearest common ancestor with `.unrelated`. This may, unfortunately, result in a lot of messy repositioning.

```css
<style>
.parent {
  position: static;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.unrelated {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background-color: #00f;
  height: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: 2;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Child element
  </div>
</div>

<div class="unrelated">
  Unrelated element
</div>
```

Comment: this worked, but now i can't use flex which completely ruined my layout . thank you though, now that i understand the problem properly i can actually figure out what to do.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that! Maybe the code refactoring will turn out to be less work than disrupting your layout :-O